# Make modal view in popover also transparent

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipopovercontroller

I have an iPad app and an UIPopoverController with a TableViewController.
I then show a modal UITableViewController like this:

```
navigationController.viewControllers = @[detailViewController];
navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
[self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This works just fine, but the modal background isn't blurred translucent anymore.

I tried `[self.view setAlpha:0.0]` shows the underlying controller (which I think, is also the problem). Maybe I have to hide the underlying UITableViewController.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Making the view's alpha 0 will effect all the subviews, so thats probs not what you want.

Comment: Have you tried setting background colors to [UIColor clearColor], instead of changing alphas?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I mean the blurred background. With a bit transpareny.